# Bash: Listing all file with .addr_book without file extensions

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, ls

I wish to list all files in current directory with the file extension ".addr_book" without the extension being visible.

I have used  `ls | sed -e 's/\..*$//'` but this displays all files in current directory. Is there a way to have it so it only displays .addr_book files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for file in *.addr_book; do
    echo "${file%.addr_book}" # removes the trailing '.addr_book' from $file
done
```

Comment: Another solution using `GNU parallel`: `parallel echo {.} ::: *.addr_book`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `basename`:

```
for i in *.addr_book; do
  basename "$i" .addr_book
done
```

From `man basename`:

```
   basename NAME [SUFFIX]
   ...
   Print  NAME  with  any leading directory components removed.  If speci‐
   fied, also remove a trailing SUFFIX.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for f in *.addr_book; do 
  [ -e "$f" ] && printf "%s\n" "${f%.*}"
done
```

`[ -e "$f" ]` is used in case there are no *.addr_book files present, otherwise there would be a false result..

Comment: This or `shopt -s nullglob`.

Answer (score -1):

You could do some like this:

```
ls | awk -F"\.addr_book" 'NF>1 {print $1}'
```

This will divide all file name using `.addr_book` as separator.
If number field is larger then `1` print first part.

Comment: Hi Jotne, there should be a backslash in front of the `.`  and (theoretically, probably not in practise) there could be an issue with a file like `a.addr_book.2nd.title.addr_book` for example..  Greetings...

Comment: @chepner interesting reading, but its very hypothetical.  How often have you seen newline in a file name ;)  I guess 99.99% uses normal characters in file name.

Comment: I see no reason to suggest a method that *might* break over one that *will not*.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend this very easy way I use often:

(Option -C1 formats the ls output to one column only, being this the file name)

ls -C1 *.addr_book | awk -F. '{ print $1 }'

Hope this helps!

Daniel.